# Align the select and Input and Button HTML elements in one row

Tags: html, css, alignment

Can some one help me lining Select Drop down, Input and Submit button in one row.

I am getting only Input and Button aligned in row but Select is going upside.

I tried below in CSS but didn't work

```
display : inline;
```

Can you please help to modify the CSS to align all in one row.

***[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2x93tfav/)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution ,I just need to make

inline-flex =>inline-flex makes the container inline while still retaining the flex layout properties.

```
display : inline-flex;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a bit everywhere. Also, "selecter" should be spelled "selector", but that is beside the point. Use more `<div>` elements to wrap around smaller code segments. For example:

```
    <div>
        <div class="item"><p>Hello</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p>Stack</p></div>
        <div class="item"><p>Overflow!</p></div>
    </div>
```

Normally, these `<div>`'s would display underneath one another. However, if we add a styling rule similar to the one you're using, we will get the result of these three elements together on one line.

```
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Wrap your button elements in a `<div>` container and style them with the above. Does this answer your question?